# python decimal print all internal decimal places

Tags: python, math, bit

i am looking for a way to print all internal decimal places of a python decimal. has anyone an idea how to achieve following. The example code is written in Python.

```
from decimal import *
bits = 32
precision = Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**bits)
val = decimal(1078947848)
```

what happens now for following if i multiply val * precision i get following result

```
val * precision
Decimal('0.2512121219187974929809570312')
```

but i know the last number 2 is not the end of my number, so i can do following which gives me this result

```
"%.100f" % x
'0.2512121219187974929809570312500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000'
```

however all the trailing zeros are not desired, and the size of %.100f depends on the given bits. It should be simple math and maybe I should give myself a break, but how can I derive the number of internal decimal places from the given number of bits 32.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html):

> the decimal module has a user alterable precision (defaulting to 28 places) which can be as large as needed for a given problem

Your number is 29 digits long, so it's just a little too much for the default precision. Try increasing it. 29 would work for this instance, but you may wish to choose a larger number if you don't know how many decimal places you'll need later.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 100
bits = 32
precision = Decimal(1) / Decimal(2**bits)
val = Decimal(1078947848)
print val * precision
```

Result:

```
0.25121212191879749298095703125000
```

Also, you can strip those trailing zeroes with a call to `normalize`.

```
>>> print (val * precision).normalize()
0.25121212191879749298095703125
```

Comment: thanks, haven't seen that, but this helps at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could take your string representation & eliminate the trailing 0's; what is left are your "internal decimal places", which you can count.